# What is the relation between replica method and "reusable holdout" method?

Tags: model-selection, overfitting, out-of-sample

Among many methods used to detect and avoid overfitting, I am particularly interested in those two:

1. [replica method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01730)
2. [reusable holdout](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/25fe/96591144f4af3d8f8f79c95b37f415e5bb75.pdf)

My question is: what is their relation in the context of adaptive data analysis and model selection? To be more concrete, let's focus on developing a multivariate logistic classifier. We are given a dataset of $N$ $D$-dimensional points $x$ associated with binary labels $y$. $N$ and $D$ are large. We want to select which dimensions (i.e. variables) of $x$ should be used by the classifier. Is it possible to say which method of the above two would in general be better for this purpose? If yes, which one?